# Google Maps: add listener to dynamically created marker outside initialize function

Tags: ajax, google-maps, infowindow

I have been trying for days to add an event listener for an infoWindow to markers that are created on Ajax success.

The `mouseover` event is never fired, so there must be something I'm doing wrong in adding the listener.

The listener that does NOT work is for the marker `restMarker`.  The `dragend` listener for `addressMarker` in the `initialize()` function works fine.

I have tried adding the listener in multiple ways: `google.maps.event.addListener(markerObject,'mouseover',function(){})` and `markerObject.addListener('mouseover',function(){})`.

I have tried giving the `restMarker` global scope.

I have read the following:

[Dynamically Adding Listeners To Google Maps Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220063/dynamically-adding-listeners-to-google-maps-markers)

[create event listener to dynamically created google-map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889457/create-event-listener-to-dynamically-created-google-map-marker)

...and more.

I have infoWindows working fine with dynamically created markers in other projects.  The only difference I'm aware of in the working projects is that the markers are created in the map `initialize()` function instead of in an ajax success function.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var zoneMap;
    var currentRestMarkers = [];
    var markerInfoWindow;

    var distances = [{"fee":2,"distance":5,"available":1},{"fee":3,"distance":7,"available":1},{"available":1,"distance":9,"fee":7},{"fee":9,"available":0,"distance":10}];

    var ajaxResponse = {"success":[{"duration":"11.5","name":"Backyard Bistro","lng":-78.7253,"lat":35.7989,"distance":6.64,"restId":"179"},{"lat":35.7796,"lng":-78.6758,"restId":"180","distance":7.5,"name":"Baja Burrito","duration":"13.3"},{"name":"Mi Rancho","duration":"15.6","lng":-78.6482,"lat":35.7491,"restId":"183","distance":6.32},{"lat":35.7757,"lng":-78.6363,"distance":4.67,"restId":"188","name":"El Rodeo Downtown","duration":"13.7"},{"duration":"9.2","name":"El Rodeo North","lng":-78.6262,"lat":35.8137,"distance":3.35,"restId":"189"},{"name":"Fallon's Flowers","duration":"9.1","restId":"192","distance":2.92,"lat":35.789,"lng":-78.6507},{"lng":-78.6397,"lat":35.7742,"restId":"193","distance":4.62,"name":"Fire Wok","duration":"14.1"},{"lng":-78.6131,"lat":35.8051,"restId":"194","distance":6.21,"name":"Gateway","duration":"9.8"},{"restId":"195","distance":27.99,"lng":-79.0564,"lat":35.9152,"name":"Gift Cards ","duration":"35.6"},{"name":"Jumbo China","duration":"8.5","lng":-78.6262,"lat":35.819,"distance":2.87,"restId":"197"},{"lng":-78.6456,"lat":35.8817,"restId":"198","distance":4.93,"name":"La Rancherita","duration":"12.0"},{"duration":"8.9","name":"Mami Nora's","restId":"205","distance":3.35,"lat":35.8137,"lng":-78.6271},{"distance":2.94,"restId":"209","lat":35.7883,"lng":-78.6474,"duration":"8.0","name":"Mellow Mushroom"},{"distance":7.88,"restId":"212","lng":-78.7387,"lat":35.7878,"duration":"12.3","name":"Ole Time BBQ"},{"lng":-78.6388,"lat":35.8374,"restId":"214","distance":2.23,"duration":"7.0","name":"Piola"},{"name":"The Remedy Diner 2.0 - Brunch","duration":"11.9","lng":-78.656,"lat":35.7824,"distance":4.24,"restId":"216"},{"lng":-78.656,"lat":35.7824,"restId":"217","distance":4.24,"duration":"11.9","name":"The Remedy Diner 2.0"},{"distance":7.66,"restId":"218","lng":-78.6773,"lat":35.7777,"name":"Sammy's Tap & Grill","duration":"13.4"},{"lng":-78.621,"lat":35.8238,"distance":4.39,"restId":"219","duration":"8.4","name":"Shaba Shabu"},{"name":"Spring Rolls","duration":"5.9","distance":1.88,"restId":"220","lng":-78.6409,"lat":35.8399},{"duration":"9.6","name":"Thaiphoon","restId":"222","distance":3.2,"lat":35.7845,"lng":-78.6477},{"lat":35.7776,"lng":-78.6398,"restId":"223","distance":4.3,"duration":"11.6","name":"The Big Easy"},{"lng":-78.6433,"lat":35.8364,"restId":"225","distance":1.68,"duration":"5.5","name":"The Q Shack"},{"duration":"14.4","name":"Vic's Italian","lng":-78.6356,"lat":35.7759,"restId":"226","distance":4.72},{"restId":"227","distance":1.68,"lng":-78.6433,"lat":35.8364,"name":"Which Wich North Hills","duration":"5.5"},{"lat":35.7912,"lng":-78.6799,"restId":"245","distance":5.89,"duration":"10.5","name":"The Wild Cook's Indian Grill"},{"lng":-78.6237,"lat":35.873,"restId":"301","distance":4.68,"name":"Taj Mahal North","duration":"12.9"},{"restId":"820","distance":6.29,"lng":-78.6825,"lat":35.8986,"duration":"14.5","name":"El Dorado "},{"name":"Taza Grill","duration":"12.8","restId":"821","distance":4.84,"lat":35.8693,"lng":-78.6211},{"duration":"14.9","name":"Sassool","restId":"824","distance":6.83,"lat":35.9043,"lng":-78.6567},{"lng":-78.5797,"lat":35.8477,"distance":8.45,"restId":"830","name":"Alpaca Peruvian Charcoal Chicken","duration":"13.9"},{"distance":6.21,"restId":"831","lat":35.899,"lng":-78.653,"name":"Shish Kabob Six Forks","duration":"14.1"},{"distance":2.87,"restId":"923","lng":-78.6262,"lat":35.819,"name":"Tropical Picken Chicken","duration":"8.5"},{"duration":"10.3","name":"Wicked Taco","lat":35.7852,"lng":-78.6923,"restId":"931","distance":6.48},{"duration":"14.8","name":"Despina's Cafe","restId":"1142","distance":6.31,"lng":-78.6824,"lat":35.9015},{"duration":"4.7","name":"WhichWich Crabtree","lat":35.8391,"lng":-78.6752,"distance":1.7,"restId":"1242"},{"duration":"6.3","name":"Pharaoh's Grill at North Hills","distance":1.86,"restId":"1296","lng":-78.6434,"lat":35.8403},{"name":"Pharaoh's at the Museum","duration":"12.2","restId":"1297","distance":4.43,"lat":35.7818,"lng":-78.6386},{"restId":"1298","distance":2.54,"lng":-78.6298,"lat":35.8215,"name":"Gorilla Grill","duration":"6.5"},{"name":"My Way Tavern","duration":"9.8","lng":-78.6506,"lat":35.7872,"restId":"1307","distance":3.04}]};

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.8013,-78.6409);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        zoneMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        var addressMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: zoneMap.center,
            map: zoneMap,
            clickable: true,
            draggable: true,
            flat: true,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(addressMarker, 'dragend', function(event) {
            var markerNewLatLng=event.latLng;

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': markerNewLatLng}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    showAvailableRests(markerNewLatLng.lat(),markerNewLatLng.lng());
                } 
                else {
                    console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        });
    }


    function loadScript() {
    var acScript = document.createElement('script');
    acScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    acScript.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(acScript);
    }

    function showAvailableRests(whichLat,whichLng) {

        var rest_list = jQuery('#rest_list');
        jQuery(rest_list).empty();
        jQuery('#restCount').html('');

        if (currentRestMarkers.length > 0) {
            for (var i in currentRestMarkers) {
              currentRestMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            currentRestMarkers = [];
        }

        var restCount = 0;
        for (var i=0; i < ajaxResponse.success.length; i++ )    {

          var iconColor = 'green.png';
          var available = 1;
          var tierClass = 'tier1';

          for (var j=0; j < distances.length; j++ ) {

              if (ajaxResponse.success[i].distance >= distances[j].distance) {
              if (distances[j].available == 0) {
                available = 0;
              }
              if (j === 0) {
                iconColor = 'yellow.png';
                tierClass = 'tier2';
              }
              else if (j === 1) {
                iconColor = 'orange.png';
                tierClass = 'tier3';
              }
              else if (j > 1) {
                iconColor = 'purple.png';
                tierClass = 'tier4';
              }
            }
            else {
              break; // if it is not greater than the shorter distance, it is not greater than longer ones either
            }
          }

          if (available === 0) { // if this restaurant is not available at this distance
            //continue; // skip the rest for unavailable
            iconColor = 'red.png';
            tierClass = 'unavailable';
          }

          else {
            restCount++;
          }

          var restDiv = jQuery(document.createElement('div'));
          var distanceTier = jQuery(document.createElement('span')).html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;').addClass('distance-tier ' + tierClass).appendTo(restDiv);
          var restDist = jQuery(document.createElement('span')).html(ajaxResponse.success[i].distance + ' mi.').addClass('rest-distance').appendTo(restDiv);
          var restName = jQuery(document.createElement('span')).html(ajaxResponse.success[i].name).addClass('rest-name').appendTo(restDiv);
          jQuery(restDiv).appendTo(rest_list);

          var restMarkerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(ajaxResponse.success[i].lat,ajaxResponse.success[i].lng);
          var restMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: restMarkerPosition,
            map: zoneMap,
            clickable: false,
            draggable: false,
            flat: true,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + iconColor
          });

          currentRestMarkers.push(restMarker);

          google.maps.event.addListener(restMarker, 'mouseover', function(e) {
            console.log('mouseover event fired');  // the mouseover event is never fired!!!
            showRestWindow(e, ajaxResponse.success[i].name, ajaxResponse.success[i].distance);
          });

          /*restMarker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                        new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: "<div><strong>" + ajaxResponse.success[i].name + "<\/strong><br>" + ajaxResponse.success[i].distance + " miles<\/div>",
                            disableAutoPan: true,
                        });
            markerInfoWindow.open(zoneMap, this);
          });*/

          jQuery('#restCount').html(restCount);
        }
    }

    function showRestWindow(event, name, distance) {
        markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<div><strong>" + name + "<\/strong><br>" + distance + " miles<\/div>",
            disableAutoPan: true,
            position: event.latLng,
        });
    markerInfoWindow.open(zoneMap);            
    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        loadScript();
        return false;
    });

    </script>

<div id='map_container'>
    <div id='map_canvas'></div>
</div>
<div id='column_right'>
    <p><b>Available Restaurants: <span id='restCount'></span></b></p>
    <div id='rest_list'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the data returned from `showRestAvailable` look like?  If I run the existing code, I don't get an `InfoWindow`, but without the results of `showRestAvailable` there are no listeners (either click or mouseover) on the marker. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Here's a minimal, complete, verifiable example:
http://www.xitechusa.com/infoWindowTest.html

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**, not a link to an external site

Comment: Sorry, I built that page and linked to it in order to give a complete, minimal example.  I updated the question with the example.

Comment: Is my updated example helpful, or do you need more info?  Thanks very much for your time!